# Where can I see my search history in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I would like to see my search history in Google Scholar.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that the search history would be viewable on some Google websites (e.g. https://www.google.com/history‎
but I don't see it there) as I use different computers. I'll look at this SQLite db tomorrow to see what it contains though, it's better than nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot see one's search history in Google Scholar.

Answer (score -1):

You can now see your most recent searches by clicking the search box. Alternatively you can press the down arrow key when the box is selected and you have not yet typed anything.